# Como agregar un valor por defecto al crear usuarios con el comando createsuperuser de Django

Tags: django, djangorestframework

como puedo personalizar el el comportamiento de la creación de usuarios a través del comando `createsuperuser`, es decir cree una clase `User` personaliza que hereda del `AbstratUser` y agregué el atributo `role` al mismo, lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de crear un usuario administrador a través del comando `createsuperuser` se asigne el valor `admin` al atributo `role`. Así como se asigna el valor `True` al `is_superuser`, gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, investigando en el [proyecto de Django](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/how-to-add-a-default-value-when-creating-users-with-djangos-createsuperuser-command/20323), hay dos posibles soluciones:

1. El primero consiste en agregar el nuevo campo a los [REQUIRED_FIELDS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS) del usuario personalizado.
2. Si la solución anterior no es suficiente,se puede crear un [comando de administración personalizado](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) para crear usuarios.